# how to skip first line when reading a csv in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to skip the first col of first row and compare each element with string.
 Java Code

```
 String csvFileToRead = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\Tasks.csv";        
            BufferedReader br = null; 
            String[] Task = null;
            String line;  
              String splitBy = ",";
              br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead)); 
              System.out.println("Excel data for Subejct: ");
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {            
                Task = line.split(splitBy); 
                System.out.println(Task[0]);    
               }
```

Comment: what do you mean by skip the first column of first row? Does it mean ignore after reading?

Comment: and what do you mean by 'compare each element with string'?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag yeah i want to ignore after reading or don't wanna read 1st row.

Comment: @k-mera 1st i want to read the columns from file and after want to compare that is matching of mismatching.

Comment: Jackson CSV will skip it for you. http://demeranville.com/how-not-to-parse-csv-using-java/

Comment: @AdnanGhaffar now I understand, see my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

To skip the first row just do a `br.readLine()`. To skip the first column start iterating the cells at `1` instead of `0`.

See this example:

```
br.readLine(); //skips the first row
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] cells = line.split(splitBy);
    //starting from 1 essentially skips the first column
    for (int col = 1; col < cells.length; col++) {
        if (cells[col].equals(someString)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `br.readLine()` outise the loop, for the row jump. 
For printing all cols but the first one do:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Task.lenght ; ++i){
 System.out.println(Task[i]);
}
```